# Deriving marginal probability $p(y) = \int_x \mathcal{N}(y | Ax+b) \mathcal{N}(x) dx$

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

In the context of Maximum Likelihood PCA, we have a Normal distributed variable:

\begin{align}
p(x) &= \mathcal{N}(x | \mu, \Lambda^{-1})
\end{align}

that we use to create another Normal variable:

\begin{align}
p(y | x) &= \mathcal{N}(y | Ax + b, L^{-1})
\end{align}

We are interested in the marginal distribution

$$
p(y) = \int_x p(y| x) p (x) dx = \mathcal{N}(y | A\mu + b, L^{-1} + A\Lambda^{-1}A^T)
$$

While there are some simple ways to demonstrate this result, I'm trying an explicit demonstration. I multiply both distributions, and I try to play with the terms in the exponent, completing the squares and so on. After many tries, I've surrendered.

Can someone give a derivation or give some reference where it is explicitly done?

(The above equations are taken from Bishop. Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning, page 689)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$p(y) = \int_x p(y| x) p (x) dx = \int_x \mathcal{N}(y | Ax + b, L^{-1})\mathcal{N}(x | \mu, \Lambda^{-1})dx$$
After expanding and factorizing, you can show (by removing terms that do not depend on $x$)
$$p(y) \propto \int_x exp ( - \frac{1}{2} x^T \Gamma x + c^Tx ) dx$$
where $\Gamma = A^TLA + \Lambda$ and $c = A^TL(y-b) + \Lambda\mu$.

Referring to [https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf], the above integral gives
$$p(y) \propto  exp \big(-\frac{1}{2} (y^TLy - 2y^TLb)  \big).exp (\frac{1}{2} c^T \Gamma^{-T} c ) $$

So
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
log(p(y))
& \propto
-\frac{1}{2} (y^TLy - 2y^TLb -c^T \Gamma^{-1} c)  
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Keeping terms that depend on $y$, you get
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
log(p(y))
&\propto
-\frac{1}{2}[y^T \Big(L - LA\Gamma^{-1}A^TL \Big) y - 2y^T\Big(Lb - LA\Gamma^{-1}(A^TLb - \Lambda\mu)\Big)  ]
\\&= -\frac{1}{2}[y^T \Big(L - LA\Gamma^{-1}A^TL \Big) y - 2y^T\Big( \big(L - LA\Gamma^{-1}A^TL \big)b + LA\Gamma^{-1}\Lambda\mu\Big)]  
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Note that by Matrix Inversion Lemma:
$$(*)\quad \Big(L - LA\Gamma^{-1}A^TL \Big) = \Big( L^{-1} + A\Lambda^{-1}A^T \Big)^{-1} = \Omega^{-1}$$
Also note
\begin{equation}\label{eq3.1.1}
\begin{split}
(**)\quad LA\Gamma^{-1}\Lambda\mu
&=
LA(A^TLA + \Lambda)^{-1}\Lambda\mu
\\&= LA(\Lambda^{-1} - \Lambda^{-1}A^{T}\Omega^{-1}A\Lambda^{-1})\Lambda\mu \qquad \text{(By Matrix Inversion Lemma)}
\\&=(L - LA\Lambda^{-1}A^{T}\Omega^{-1})A\mu
\\&=(L\Omega - LA\Lambda^{-1}A^{T})\Omega^{-1}A\mu
\\&=\Big(L(L^{-1} + A\Lambda^{-1}A^T ) - LA\Lambda^{-1}A^{T} 
\\&=\Big(I + LA\Lambda^{-1}A^T  - LA\Lambda^{-1}A^{T} \Big)\Omega^{-1}A\mu
\\&=\Omega^{-1}A\mu 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Plug $(*)$ and $(**)$ in $log(p(y))$, you get
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
log(p(y))
&\propto
-\frac{1}{2}[y^T \Big(L - LA\Gamma^{-1}A^TL \Big) y - 2y^T\Big(Lb - LA\Gamma^{-1}(A^TLb - \Lambda\mu)\Big)  ]
\\&= -\frac{1}{2}[y^T \Omega^{-1} y - 2y^T\Big( \Omega^{-1}b + \Omega^{-1}A\mu \Big)]  
\\&= -\frac{1}{2}[y^T \Omega^{-1} y - 2y^T\Omega^{-1}\Big( A\mu + b \Big)]
\\&\propto
-\frac{1}{2}\Big( \big(y - (A\mu + b)\big)^T\Omega^{-1} \big(y - (A\mu + b)\big)\Big)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
And you're done.

Comment: Thanks a lot @El Bazzi. Could you specify where in the Matrix Cookbook did you take the result of the integral from?

Comment: Sure..Page 40/72, equation 346 has 5 "subequations", it's the 4th one.

Comment: The transposed $\Gamma^{-T}$ should be an inversed $\Gamma^{-1}$ instead, shouldn't it?

Comment: Actually it's the same since $\Gamma^{-T} = (\Gamma^{T})^{-1} = ((A^TLA + \Lambda)^T)^{-1}= (A^TL^TA + \Lambda^T)^{-1}$. Since $L$ and $\Lambda$ are covariance matrices, then $L^T = L$ and $\Lambda^T = \Lambda$ (Covariance matrices are symmetric)

Comment: I got the covariance, but I'm stuck in the mean. I got $\mu_y =  (L^{-1}  + A \Lambda A^T)
(L A \Gamma^{-1}
(A^T L b - \Lambda \mu )
- L b
)$

Comment: I had a typo i will correct now, and explain below

Comment: Yeah I got that one :) I couldn't have got te covariance otherwise

Comment: After solving some mistakes I got to this expression for the mean $\Sigma_y
(L A \Gamma^{-1} \Lambda\mu) +b$

Comment: I have edited the answer.. Please see above